# Is there a safe way to perform pointer arithmetic in C# prior to .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, pointers

I discovered this evening that some helper code I wrote is the culprit of a rather nasty `SIGSERV` crash on 64-bit machines due to the casting of a 64-bit pointer down to 32-bits.

```
class FastPixelEditor {
    Bitmap m_bitmap;
    Rectangle m_source;
    BitmapData m_bitmapData;
    int m_nativePixelPointer;
    public FastPixelEditor(Bitmap bitmap, Rectangle source) {
        m_bitmap = bitmap;
        m_source = source;
        m_bitmapData = m_bitmap.LockBits(source, 
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        m_nativePixelPointer = m_bitmapData.Scan0.ToInt32();
    }
    public void SetPixel(int x, int y, Color color) {
        int idx = (y - m_source.Top) * m_source.Width + 
            (x - m_source.Left); 
        idx *= 4;
        Marshal.WriteInt32((IntPtr)(m_nativePixelPointer + idx), 
            color.ToArgb());
    }
    public Color GetPixel(int x, int y) {
        int idx = (y - m_source.Top) * m_source.Width + 
            (x - m_source.Left);
        idx *= 4;
        return Color.FromArgb(Marshal.ReadInt32((IntPtr)(
            m_nativePixelPointer + idx)));
    }
    public void Unlock() { m_bitmap.UnlockBits(m_bitmapData); }
}
```

The crash occurs on this line in the `GetPixel` function:

```
Marshal.ReadInt32((IntPtr)(m_nativePixelPointer + idx))
```

Being helper code, I doubt it's prudent to force anyone using this code to set the `/unsafe` compilation flag on their project, but using `IntPtr.ToInt64()` seems really hackish (though it probably works).

[`IntPtr.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.add.aspx) seems to be exactly what I'm after, but this code must target .NET 2.0, and `IntPtr.Add` was added in .NET 4.0.

Am I forced to decide between `/unsafe` or `IntPtr.ToInt64()` or is there another option?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should be using the stride value in your Y multiply, not the width.

Comment: Using `Marshal.WriteInt32` doesn't make your code safer than using unsafe pointers, but it makes it less readable and slower. You shouldn't be afraid to flip the `/unsafe` switch in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just noticed that `Marshall.ReadInt32` and `Marshall.WriteInt32` actually have overloads that permit an offset to be specified:

[`Marshall.ReadInt32(IntPtr ptr, int ofs)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17bxe5tf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

And they are available in .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

`IntPtr.Add` is defined as below:

```
return ptr + offset;
```

The `operator+` overload for `IntPtr` is defined as below:

```
return new IntPtr(pointer.ToInt64() + (long)offset);
```

So.. its essentially doing what you've suggested.. its just wrapping it in a nicer function call. You could do the same.

Comment: When you say *defined* is that to say that that is how the `.NET Framework` implemented it? Or that `Mono` and other CLRs must implement it that way to be conformant?

Comment: That is how it is defined in mscorlib.dll in the .NET Framework.

Comment: Using a decompiler?  That (long) cast isn't actually there.